# Java Maven Build: Thread.sleep doesn't work (in eclipse it does)

Tags: java, multithreading, maven, sleep

I've got a strange error. My code is the following:

```
    LoginQueue queue = new LoginQueue(server);
    QueueTimer timer = queue.waitInQueue(this.username, this.password);
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(6000);
    while (!timer.isFinished()) {

        if (timer.getPosition() != 0L) {
            log("Queue Position" + server.toString() + ":"
                    + String.valueOf(timer.getPosition()), LogLevel.DEBUG);
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(3000);
        }
```

My goal is to login to the League of Legends servers using the open source riotapi: https://github.com/loldevs/riotapi/

The problem isn't LoL specific, so no problem there. When I create the `QueueTimer`, it needs some time to retrieve some data from the server, otherwise `timer.getPosition()` will throw a `NullPointerException`. That's why I wait 6 seconds before going on. In Eclipse debugging it all works fine, but after exporting it with `m2eclipse` (clean package as goals; I'm new to Maven if that matters), the compiled JAR doesn't sleep. It just goes on and then throws my `NullPointerException` because it didn't wait. Why does my code behave in Eclipse and doesn't work outside? What am I doing wrong? I've tried `Thread.sleep()` instead of `Thread.currentThread().sleep()`, doesn't work either.

Edit:

I changed it to:

```
LoginQueue queue = new LoginQueue(server);
String authkey = queue.waitInQueueBlocking(this.username, this.password);
```

So I am using synchronous methods now. Now I get the following stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "Queue Timer for LeagueAlerter" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.setupOutInterceptorChain(AbstractClient.java:840)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient.createMessage(AbstractClient.java:902)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.finalizeMessage(WebClient.java:1068)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doChainedInvocation(WebClient.java:1049)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:854)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.doInvoke(WebClient.java:825)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient.invoke(WebClient.java:393)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient$SyncInvokerImpl.method(WebClient.java:1582)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient$SyncInvokerImpl.method(WebClient.java:1577)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient$SyncInvokerImpl.post(WebClient.java:1517)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.spec.InvocationBuilderImpl.post(InvocationBuilderImpl.java:141)
        at net.boreeas.riotapi.loginqueue.LoginQueue.getAuthToken(LoginQueue.java:54)
        at net.boreeas.riotapi.loginqueue.QueueTimer.run(QueueTimer.java:89)
```

The error seems to be somewhere in the Riot API. But why does it work inside eclipse? I am too stupid to understand the API source, would be so cool if someone helped (Github is https://github.com/loldevs/riotapi/ ). My pom.xml: http://pastebin.com/jik5ba8J

Comment: `Thread.sleep()` is the proper way to call it. It is a static method. You cannot make any other thread but the current sleep.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't just use `queue.waitInQueueBlocking` ?

Comment: I don't use queue.waitInQueueBlocking to show my current position in the login queue which is only possible with my async call. But anyways, queue.waitInQueueBlocking doesn't work outside eclipse either. Then it just throws an NPException at the next usage of the queue!

Comment: You could use a try/catch block to see if an `IllegalStateException` is being thrown by `timer.getPosition`, which is what it throws if it hasn't received a result back from the server yet.

Comment: My best guess is that in Eclipse you get the configuration properly set up, but when running standalone, you don't. The missing configuration causes NPE.

Comment: There is no real configuration. No arguments etc. at all. I just run my main class and outside eclipse I do java -jar file.jar. I'm gonna add my POM.XML to the post. (exporting with maven clean package)

Comment: Ok, this seems to be a Maven problem. When exporting the jar without dependencies and then copying them manually, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Hey fellow ${search engine of choice}ers!

I had the same problem when running the .jar of my application which was built by maven.

Turns out that

1. I was using the maven assembly plugin to generate the jar. This plugin will (at least by default) put all the dependency resources directly in the produced jar file
2. CXF has some overlapping resources (which means trouble because of pt. 1)

I replaced the assembly plugin with the one-jar plugin (which adds dependencies as jar files in the produced binary) and after this everything worked fine.